# Xpath - HTML :: How can be selected element according his value and class with xpath?

Tags: php, html, xpath

How can be selected element according his value and class  with xpath?

The case:**Need xpath for class="my_class" + element value = 'First element value'**

```
text....
    <div class="my_class"> First element value </div>
text... 
<div class="my_class"> Second element value </div>
text...
<div class="not_my_class"> First element value </div>
text..
```

Update:
please if you can write full code: xpath + php or other program language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath will give you the first  element in your example:

```
//div[.='First element value' and @class='my_class']
```

However you probably don't want to use the `//` operator; use a specific path instead. This works in XMLSpy, not sure about in any languages' XML implementations.

Comment: please can you give php example with xpath that you write?

Comment: @Yosef: sorry, I don't really know PHP. However, this question looks like it might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230592

Comment: what meaning of //div instead just div?

Comment: @Yosef: `//div` means *all `div` elements descendant from document root* and `div` means *all `div` elements children of context node*

Comment: +1 Good answer. As a minor, do note that `@class` in (X)HTML probably holds a sequence.