# PHP: getting value of XML element by attribute

Tags: php, xml

I'm getting a xml using the file_get_contents function and then creating a SimpleXMLElement with it.

The xml file can be seen here: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=Nirvana&api_key=0ca5b0824b7973303c361510e7dbfced

The problem is that I need to get the value of lfm->artist->image[@size='small'] and I can't find how to do it.

Comment: This seems to moving in your direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837479/php-and-xml-looping-through-an-xml-file-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DOMXPath for this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

This XPath query would work for your XML:

`\\lfm\artist\image[@size='small']`

As follows:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($url);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("\\lfm\artist\image[@size='small']");


if (!is_null($elements)) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";

    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: XPath is also available from SimpleXMLElement object by using `xpath()` function. See: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php and yes, this way it's looks like the easiest.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

$requestXML = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&api_key=0ca5b0824b7973303c361510e7dbfced&artist=$artist');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($requestXML);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
echo $xpath->query("\\lfm\artist\image[@size='small']");

Comment: Eliminate  the `file_get_contents` and `loadXML` lines altogether. Instead use loadHTMLFile() and pass in the XML url. See edited.

Comment: it shows warnings of invalid tag for every xml element in the line with  $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

Comment: See edited, you should use loadXML instead of loadHTML if your loading an XML document.

Comment: Still not working :s

"Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in Entity, line: 1"

Comment: Glad to help, please mark as solution if answer was helpful.