# How to parse deep xml on php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have problem with that XML parsing:

```
<pricecatalog>
    <pricecathdr></pricecathdr>
    <listofcatalogdetails>

        <catalogitem>
        <product>
           <productid>1515159115</productid>
        </product>
        </catalogitem>

        <catalogitem>
        <product>
           <productid>251541851</productid>
        </product>
        </catalogitem>

        <catalogitem>
        <product>
           <productid>15181158</productid>
        </product>
        </catalogitem>

    </listofcatalogdetails>
</pricecatalog>
```

I use DOM to parse it like that:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($this->response);
    $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("catalogitem");
    $i = 0;
    foreach($items as $itm){
        $i++;
    }
    echo $i;
```

I think I have to get 2 if parse will success but I allays get 0.

Comment: I would use XPath to query an XML document because it's very easy.

See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230592/xpath-query-with-php)

Comment: The example you gave above works on my system. Are you sure `$this->response` contains the XML given above?