# How to filter by id with Symfony 2 Dom Crawler?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

This works

```
$this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('.elementClass')->count()); // filter by class
```

But, this doesn't seem to work.

```
$this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('#elementId')->count()); // filter by id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Adding the composer package, `"symfony/css-selector"` will add support for searching by CSS id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Symfony2 DOM Crawler filter internally uses DOMXPath, so you can find answer for your question on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230592/xpath-query-with-php)

query for filter should be something like(note that code bellow is untested, I'm sure link above will help you)

```
//*[@id='elementId']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used both filter() and filterXPath() methods. But, they didn't work.

Comment: You have tried something like $crawler->filter('//yourtagname[@id="1"]')->count() and it didnt work?

Comment: By the way, I am filtering HTML, not XML.

Comment: $crawler->filter('//yourtagname[@id="1"]')->count() shows error "Unexpected symbol". $crawler->filterXPath('//yourtagname[@id="1"]')->count() does not show error. But, it cannot find the element with id.

Comment: Yup it seams that filter should work only for css selectors (https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler/blob/master/Crawler.php) **
     * Filters the list of nodes with a CSS selector.
     *
     * This method only works if you have installed the CssSelector Symfony Component.

Comment: I dont think filtering tags in HTML should be different than filtering XML tags. Maybe you can omit one / like "/yourtagname[@id='elementId']" . I can not try code on my machine right now, so i'm guessing

Comment: I installed CssSelector. Otherwise, my filter with class shouldn't have worked.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I just copypasted more text then I should :) I just wanted to say that you should use filterXPath for your need. filter method is only for css

Comment: No, it didn't. It is really strange.

Comment: You marked this answer as correct, do you solve problem and what is the final solution?

Comment: You were right. Even $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('#elementId')->count()); works. In my company, we use short open tags. I forgot to enable that. Thank you very much for your help, icrew. Beware, short open tags are bad :(.